# TeamCity - SVN and Labelling

Tags: svn, tags, label, teamcity-5.0

I'm about to start using the labeling feature of TC (Great product :)) and have a question:

I have 1 root VCS:     **svn:\someserver\MyRepo**

With label rule:       **trunk=>tags**

And in all my projects I use checkout rules to only checkout the needed projects like so:

**Prj1 - Conf1:**
+:MyPrj1/trunk => /

**Prj2 - Conf1:**
+:MyPrj2/trunk => /

**Prj3 - Conf1:**
+:MyPrjCollection/MySubPrj1/trunk => /

... you get the picture

What will then happen if I set auto label on each successfull build on ex. **Prj1 - Conf1?**

**A. Will my trunk simply be label into MyPrj1/tags/LabelName, as i'm hoping for?**

**B. Or will the entire root VCS be labeled (MyRepo\tags\Label) or something worse?**

Can anyone help me? :)

Kind regards
Garrett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read [VCS Labeling (TC6)](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/VCS+Labeling) correctly, Labeling rules are specified as newline-delimited rules each using the following format:

```
TrunkOrBranchRepositoryPath => tagDirectoryRepositoryPath
```

So instead of having a generic label rule  `trunk=>tags`, why not having labeling rules like:

```
/MyPrj1/trunk=>/MyPrj1/tags
/MyPrj2/trunk=>/MyPrj2/tags
/MyPrjCollection/MySubPrj1/trunk=>/MyPrjCollection/MySubPrj1/tags
```

That way, you would be sure of the resulting tree structure.

Comment: Hi

thats a bit more work than the generic rule but much better than creating a whole new vcs root :). 
I realized that i could just create a sandbox repo to test the feature with so thats what i Will do. And at the same time test both options and see the result.

Thanks for your help. 

Kind regards
Garrett

Comment: @Garrett: you are welcome :) I am interested by your feedback and see if this works like you want.

Comment: Hi first of I tried going with the default trunk=>tags, but TC gave me a nice warning telling me that there where no label rule matching my checkout rule :). How cool is that, nice one team TC :).

So I tried setting up the rules as you recommended and it works :).
The only down side is that one has to add a new labelling rule in the shared VCS root everytime a new project is added. But I can live with that :).

Thanks for your help :)

Kind regards
Garrett